# Can I get AVX support on my new MacBook Air (M1 CPU)?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon

I have an Intellij plugin which requires AVX, but when I launch IntelliJ it opens a window stating that my computer does not support AVX.

Is it at all possible to fix this?

Comment: Neither the M1 not Rosetta2 support AVX. idk if there is any workaround, but I doubt it. idk enough about the subject, so I'll leave the actual answer to someone more knowledgeable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AVX](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/36945) (Advanced Vector Extensions) is an extension of the x86 instruction set. It is not available on the M1 CPU. Moreover the [documentation of Rosetta](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/about-the-rosetta-translation-environment) state that:

> Rosetta translates all x86_64 instructions, but it doesn’t support the execution of some newer instruction sets and processor features, such as AVX, AVX2, and AVX512 vector instructions.

So to answer your question: no there is no way, for now, to run your IntelliJ plugin on an M1 CPU.